# Embedded memory allocation and scope

Tags: c, memory, scope, atmega, avr-gcc

If I want to create a structure initialization functions that return a pointer to the initialized structure members, will the allocated memory to the data array in **new_foo** still be valid outside the function?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct structure{
    char* data;
    size_t num;
}foo_t;


foo_t* new_foo(size_t num);

int main(void){
    foo_t* foo = new_foo(32);
    while(1){;}
}

foo_t* new_foo(size_t num){
    foo_t* self;
    char temp[num];
    self->data = temp;

    self->num = num;

    return self;
}
```

I wanted to take a look at the assembly code to see if anything jumped out at me, the only thing that potentially makes me thing memory is still valid is that there are no stack operations associated with

```c
char temp[num];
self->data = temp;
```

but it's been a while since I had to look at assembly code.

https://godbolt.org/z/5Wx4TY

[EDIT] Modified new_foo

```c
foo_t* new_foo(size_t num){
    static foo_t self = {NULL, 0};
    char data_array[num];
    self.data = temp;

    self.num = num;

    return &self;
}
```

Comment: *there are no stack operations* There's no guarantee that will be true.

Comment: wouldn't looking at the assembly code tell you that?

Comment: Now recompile your code with different options, or on another platform.  Are you planning on examining assembly code every time you compile in order to check if you got away with undefined behavior in your source code?

Comment: No stack operations? Typically (but not necessarily) local variables `self` and `temp` will be stored on the stack, and be popped on function return. Certainly their life will end, although the (indeterminate) value of `self` is returned.

Comment: @WeatherVane could you elaborate on why its indeterminate? Is self not just a pointer to a structure made of a char* and size_t. The data and num are subsequently initialized directly after.

Comment: `foo_t* self` has an indeterminate vale because it never has any value assigned to it. As a local (automatic) variable there is no 'default' value. `self` is a pointer, but when it is dereferenced with `self->data` etc, it is not known where it is pointing to.

Comment: So making it a static variable would inilize it to zero and also permently place it in RAM? 
[edit]: Or just finalizing it in general

Comment: It is `temp` that is the *real* worry, the thing that `self->data` is supposed to point to. You have returned the pointer value. One way round it would be to define `foo_t self;` as an actual `struct`, not a pointer, and return the `struct` instead of a pointer to it. But it is `char temp[num];` that needs to persist, despite its unfortunate name.

Comment: Would something like the modifications to new_foo, be more appropriate?

Comment: Please don't change the code with updates from comments/answers. This isn't an interactive code improvement site. It is better to add extra code to the question, or ask a new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218928/discussion-between-lpaulson-and-weather-vane).

Comment: The proposal looks good except for the typo `temp`, and the function `foo_t* new_foo(size_t num)` should be `foo_t new_foo(size_t num)` and `return self;`. It's an actual `struct` that is returned. There is no need to initialise `foo_t self = {NULL, 0};` because you are about to write to both its members anyway. Remember that using static variables isn't safe: if you call the same function again the previous `data_array` will be shared/trashed by another usage. Better to `malloc` the array.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. I was under the impression is wasn't a good idea to use malloc in embedded systems without an MMU. This code is for an 8-bit microcontroller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function has undefined behavior.

```
foo_t* new_foo(size_t num){
    foo_t* self;
    char temp[num];
    self->data = temp;

    self->num = num;

    return self;
}
```

For starters the pointer `self` is not initialized and has indeterminate value.

The variable length array `temp` is a local variable of the function that will not be alive after exiting the function. So any pointer to it returned from the function will be invalid.

Comment: Does it matter that its uninitialized, since it will be initialized immediately after? Secondly so the pointer to self and all members assosiated with it could be corrupted by other code?

Comment: @Lpaulson I do not see where it is initialized.  There is an access to the data member data of a non-existent object.

Comment: Is the self object not created without inilization paramaters?

Comment: @Lpaulson The pointer does not point to a valid object. So you may not access data members of the structure using this pointer.